# How to inject multiple instances of a services in eclipse e4?

Tags: java, eclipse, dependency-injection, eclipse-rcp, e4

Neither `@Inject MyService[] services` nor `@Inject Collection<MyService>` works to get multiple instances of the same service.

It seems like the eclipse guys don't provide a "simple" solution, see: [Bug 413147](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=413147).

Lars Vogel suggest:

> I think the correct solution for customers desire that functionality is to define an extended object supplier. Currently we have no plan to support the injection of multiple values via DI.

But how to do it, i cant find anything about it? Or should i use a ServiceTracker instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a class extending `ExtendedObjectSupplier` to provide an implementation of a qualifier annotation for injection. So if your annotation is `@MyService` you can do:

```
@Inject @MyService
MyService [] services;
```

The extended object supplier class is responsible for finding the values to be injected. So you might use `ServiceTracker` in the supplier.

More on using `ExtendedObjectSupplier` [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4OwnAnnotations/article.html)

Update a summary of using ExtendedObjectSupplier

Create your annotation:

```
@Qualifier
@Documented
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyService {   
}
```

Create an OSGi service definition for the supplier using 'New Component Definition'

```xml
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0" name="greg.music.core.preferenceSettings">
   <implementation class="package.MyServiceObjectSupplier"/>
   <property name="dependency.injection.annotation" type="String" value="package.MyService"/>
   <service>
      <provide interface="org.eclipse.e4.core.di.suppliers.ExtendedObjectSupplier"/>
   </service>
</scr:component>
```

The MANIFEST.MF should have a reference to this file in `Service-Component`

The supplier class looks like:

```
public class MyServiceObjectSupplier extends ExtendedObjectSupplier
{
  @Override
  public Object get(final IObjectDescriptor descriptor, final IRequestor requestor, final boolean track, final boolean group)
  {
     // TODO return the object to inject
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you quote the relevant content of the link? See "Provide context for links" 
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer so others have an idea what to do, in case the linked page disappears.